# Combining latest value with last n values

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm trying to create a reactive pipeline that takes characters (0-9, *, #) entered on a [4x3 matrix keypad](https://www.adafruit.com/product/419) and displays them on a [4-digit, seven-segment display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/880). That is for every new item that is emitted, I need to combine it with the previous n=3 values.

So far I have exposed a `PublishSubject<Character> keypresses` in the Keypad controller class. This class, however, emits *all* key presses. That is, even if you press a key (e.g. 1) for only an instant, multiple 1s are emitted. So I use the `debounce` operator to ensure that only one `Character` is emitted per key press:

```
KeypadController kbc = new KeypadController();
kbc.keypresses.debounce(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribe(c -> {System.out.println(c);});
```

So far so good. At the other end of the spectrum I have the 4-digit, seven-segment display controller class. This class exposes a `writeDigit(int position, char value)` and a `clearScreen()` method. That is, if I want to display the number 7654, I need to call the method four times:

```
SevenSegmentController segment = new SevenSegmentController();
segment.writeDigit(3,'7')
segment.writeDigit(2,'6')
segment.writeDigit(1,'5')
segment.writeDigit(0,'4')
```

However, I would like the display to continually update as the user keys in digits. As the following scenario illustrates.

```
user presses 7
|----| segment.writeDigit(0,'7')
|   7|
|----|

user presses 6
|----| segment.writeDigit(1,'7')
|  76| segment.writeDigit(0,'6')
|----| 

user presses 5
|----| segment.writeDigit(2,'7') 
| 765| segment.writeDigit(1,'6') 
|----| segment.writeDigit(0,'5')

user presses 4
|----| segment.writeDigit(3,'7') 
|7654| segment.writeDigit(2,'6') 
|----| segment.writeDigit(1,'5')
       segment.writeDigit(0,'4')

Finally,
|----| Display clears after timeout (1000ms without input)
|    | or if user presses 5th key
|----| segment.clearScreen()
```

The [`ReplaySubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html) with its `createWithTimeAndSize` method looked promising as it retains at most a given number of items that are also not older than a specified time amount. However, this behavior is only exhibited upon subscribing, after which Observers continuously receive from that point on.  Is there a way for a ReplaySubject -- or some other rxjava class/method -- to continuously output the latest 4 digits within a specified amount of time, say 2000ms.

Comment: Did you look at the `replay()` operator? One variant will do what you want, I believe.